# ggplot2 multiple lines with multiple factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, factors

I'm writing currently my master thesis and I'm struggling with how to make a ggplot in R with multiple lines and multiple factors.

My data looks like this

- Code for each participant: XXX, YYY, ZZZ
- Group: 1, 2, 1 ,2...
- Temperature 1st Week: Cold, Warm, Hot...
- Temperature 2nd Week: Cold, warm, Hot...
- Up to 12 Weeks

To summarize: I'd like to have the tempratures sorted (Cold, Warm, Hot) on the y-axis & on the x-axis each week (Week 1, 2, 3... 12), for colour red group 1 and colour blue group 2 for EVERY participant.

What I don't get is on the Code i can only insert one column for each axis. I changed the columns to factor and sorted the levels of the temparature already. Is it possible to code it with ggplot?

```
ggplot(data1, aes(x = Temperature 1st Week, y = ???, colour = Group, group = Code)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("Showering Temperature")
```

Greetings from Switzerland

Comment: Hi! It would be helpful to know more about the structure of your data in order to provide an answer. For example, do you have a continuous variable to plot on the y axis or is it just the three temperature levels? Could you add the output of `head(data1)` and `str(data1)` to your question? I suspect the answer will involve manipulating your data from wide to long [https://uc-r.github.io/tidyr] but it is hard to tell w/o more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to first tidy up your dataset by converting from wide to long or tidy format using e.g. `tidy::pivot_longer`. Try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)

temp_levels <- c("", "Sehr kalt (12 - 20\u00B0C)", 
                 "Kalt (21 - 26\u00B0C)", 
                 "Lauwarm (27 - 34\u00B0C)", 
                 "Warm (35 - 39\u00B0C)", 
                 "Sehr warm (\u00FCber 40\u00B0C)")


# Tidy data
data2 <- data1 %>% 
  # Convert from wide to long
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Duschtemperatur"), names_to = "Woche", values_to = "Duschtemperatur") %>%
  # Missings can be dropped with the following line of code. Just remove the `#' at the beginning`
  filter(Duschtemperatur != "", !is.na(Duschtemperatur)) %>% 
  mutate(
    # Tidying week labels: `str_extract` extracts the number of the week
    Woche = paste0("Woche ", str_extract(Woche, "\\d+")),
    Gruppe = factor(Gruppe))

data2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Woche, Duschtemperatur, color = Gruppe, group = Code)) +
  geom_line() +
  # Add geom_jitter to check that all data is plot
  geom_jitter() +
  # Switched to labs instead of ggtitle, which allows for labelling title, 
  # axes, .. in one place
  labs(title = "Duschtemperatur", color = "Gruppe", x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```r
# Example data
data1 <- data.frame(
  Code = c("TURN12", "AMMN17", "LKPG08", "LJRn05", "AGBD08", "IUGH20"),
  Gruppe = c(2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2),
  StudentBasel = c("Ja", rep("Nein", 5)),
  Alter = c(50, 26, 19, 22, 24, 32), 
  Groesse = c(159, 164, 167, 180, 165, 168),
  Gewicht0W = c(70, 52, 54, 60, 49, 54),
  Gewicht12W = c(72, 50, rep(NA, 4)),
  Duschtemperatur0W = factor(temp_levels[c(5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5)], levels = temp_levels),
  Duschtemperatur1W = factor(temp_levels[c(5, 5, 4, 1, 5, 5)], levels = temp_levels),
  Duschtemperatur2W = factor(temp_levels[c(5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1)], levels = temp_levels)
)
```